# Insert in SQLite Database android

Tags: android, insert, android-sqlite

im new on Android. I have some trouble with the insert statement in the database, when im running the application the values have not been inserted. Please someone can help..

```
public class DatabaseAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
// Database attributes
public static final String DB_NAME = "MoneyManagerSystemTr";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

// Table attributes

public static final String TABLE_ACCOUNT = "account_table";

//Account Table
public static final String KEY_BANKNAME ="bankname";
public static final String KEY_TYPE = "type";
public static final String KEY_ACCNUM = "accnum";
public static final String KEY_BALANCE = "balance";
public static final String KEY_EXPIRYDATE = "expirydate";

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


    String AccountTable = "create table if not exists " + TABLE_ACCOUNT + " ( " + BaseColumns._ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
            + KEY_BANKNAME + " text not null, "
            + KEY_TYPE + " text, "
            + KEY_ACCNUM + " text, "
            + KEY_BALANCE + " text, "
            + KEY_EXPIRYDATE + " text);";

    db.execSQL(AccountTable);

String ROW1 = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_ACCOUNT + " Values ('Cash','','',0, '');";
    db.execSQL(ROW1);

    String ROW2 = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_ACCOUNT + " Values ('Bank Account','','',0, '');";
    db.execSQL(ROW2);

    String ROW3 = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_ACCOUNT + " Values ('Credit Card','','',0, '');";
    db.execSQL(ROW3);
```

Comment: What error do you get? Also, onCreate() is only executed once if the DB does not exist, maybe your DB already existed before you added the inserts? Without the error msg it's hard to say. And if you do not get any errors it might be because onCreate() is not executed.

Comment: add a try-catch block around your execSQL commands and see what you get

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remove the semicolons from your insert statements and add quotes around 0:

```
String ROW1 = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_ACCOUNT + " ("
              + KEY_BANKNAME + ", " + KEY_TYPE + ", "
              + KEY_ACCNUM + ", " + KEY_BALANCE + ", "
              + KEY_EXPIRYDATE + ") Values ('Cash', '', '', '0', '')";
db.execSQL(ROW1);
```

Better yet, heed the suggestion at [execSQL()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29) and use [insert()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) instead.

Comment: Yes, this is because of the missing quotes around 0, fixed now.

Comment: i think im having an error because of the id. Telling me that i have 6 columns and i have entered value only for 5.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The id column is hidden behind the scrollbar. Then you must add the column names to insert. See modified answer.

Answer (score 20):

You can use `ContentValues` to insert into your database.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(COL_NAME, VALUE); 
values.put(COL_NAME, VALUE);

// Inserting Row
db.insert(YOUR_TABLE, null, values);
```

Comment: I can see that this is cleaner, but How would one do a insert where not exists this way or must a seperate query be done for that?

Comment: @Pierre Yes, I guess so.

Answer (score 5):

1) DatabaseHelper

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String TAG = "DatabaseHelper";
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "test.db";


public static final String TABLE_NAME_2 = "updates";


private Context context;
public static final String Trigger = "fk_insert_state";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;



public static final String TABLE_2_CREATE = "Create table "
        + TABLE_NAME_2
        + " (_id integer primary key autoincrement, w_id text, title text, des text, date_text text, image_url text, video_url text,link text, con_type text, con_source text, timestamp integer, UNIQUE (_id) ON CONFLICT REPLACE)";


private static DatabaseHelper databasehelper;

public static DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {
    if (databasehelper == null)
        databasehelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    return databasehelper;

}

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


    db.execSQL(TABLE_2_CREATE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Util.customLog("Upgrade "
            + "Database has been updraded but we have'nt do anything");
}

 }
```

2)DatabaseOperation

```
 import android.content.ContentValues;

 public interface DatabaseOperation {
 public long insert(Object object);
 public int update(Object object);
 public int delete(Object object);
 ContentValues getContentValues(Object object);
 }
```

3)Data Class

```
public class UpdateData {

private int _id;
private String w_id;
private long timestamp;

public UpdateData(int _id, String w_id,  long timestamp) {
    super();
    this._id = _id;
    this.w_id = w_id;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;

}



public String getW_id() {
    return w_id;
}

public void setW_id(String w_id) {
    this.w_id = w_id;
}

public long getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}

public UpdateData() {
    super();
}

public String TableName() {
    return "updates";
}

public int get_id() {
    return _id;
}

public void set_id(int _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}

}
```

4)DataImpl

```
 import android.content.ContentValues;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class UpdateImpl implements DatabaseOperation {
SQLiteDatabase database;

public UpdateImpl(Context context) {
    DatabaseHelper databasehelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context);
    database = databasehelper.getWritableDatabase();

}

@Override
public long insert(Object object) {
    UpdateData table = (UpdateData) object;
    long result = database.insert(table.TableName(), null,
            this.getContentValues(object));
    return result;
}

public void insertAll(ArrayList<UpdateData> objects){
    database.beginTransaction();
    for (UpdateData object : objects) {
        UpdateData table = object;
        database.insert(table.TableName(), null,
                this.getContentValues(object));
    }
    database.setTransactionSuccessful();
    database.endTransaction();
}

@Override
public int update(Object object) {
    UpdateData table = (UpdateData) object;
    String[] whereArgs = { String.valueOf(table.get_id()) };
    return update(object, "_id = ?", whereArgs);
}

public int update(Object object, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs) {
    UpdateData table = (UpdateData) object;
    int result = database.update(table.TableName(),
            this.getContentValues(object), whereClause, whereArgs);
    Util.customLog("Update Result - " + result);
    return result;
}

@Override
public int delete(Object object) {
    UpdateData table = (UpdateData) object;
    String[] whereArgs = { String.valueOf(table.get_id()) };
    int result = database.delete(table.TableName(), "_id = ?", whereArgs);
    Util.customLog("Delete Result - " + result);
    return result;
}

@Override
public ContentValues getContentValues(Object object) {
    UpdateData table = (UpdateData) object;
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    // contentValues.put("_id", table.get_id());
    contentValues.put("w_id", table.getW_id());
    contentValues.put("timestamp", table.getTimestamp());

    return contentValues;

}

public List getAll() {
    List<UpdateData> itemList = new ArrayList<UpdateData>();

    String[] columnArray = { "_id,w_id , timestamp" };
    Cursor cursor = database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME_2,
            columnArray, "con_type=" + "'"+type+"' AND con_source="+"'"+source+"'", null, null, null, "timestamp DESC", null);

    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            UpdateData table = new UpdateData();
            table.set_id(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
            table.setW_id(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("w_id")));
            table.setTimestamp(cursor.getLong(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("timestamp")));

            itemList.add(table);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();
    } else {
        Util.customLog("getAll - No value found");
    }
    return itemList;
}
public void deletess(String Id)
{
    try {

        database.delete(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME_2, "cat_id="+Id, null);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {

    }
}

public int getCount_CatNomiid(String w_id,String nomi_id) {
    int res = 0;
    String[] columnArray = { "_id, cat_id, nomi_id ,status" };
    Cursor cursor = database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME_2,
            columnArray, "cat_id=" + "'" + w_id + "' AND nomi_id=" + "'"+ nomi_id + "'", null, null, null,
            null);
    if ((cursor != null) && (cursor.getCount() > 0)) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        res = res + 1;
    } else {
        res = 0;
    }
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return cursor.getCount();
}

public String deletestatus(String cat_id, String nomi_id) {
    String result = "Suceesfully Updated Status of notify";
    String qry = "'" + cat_id + "' AND nomi_id=" + "'"+ nomi_id + "'";
    Cursor cursor = database
            .rawQuery("delete " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME_2 + ""
                    + " where cat_id=" + qry, null);
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return result;
}

public String updatestatus(int id) {
    String result = "Suceesfully Updated Status of notify";
    String qry = "'" + id + "'";
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("update "
            + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME_2 + " SET status=" + "'" + "Y" + "'"
            + " where _id=" + qry, null);
    Util.customLog("updatequery: " + "update "
            + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME_2 + " SET status=" + "Y"
            + " where _id=" + id);
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return result;
}

public void deleteAll() {
    try {
        database.delete(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME_2, null, null);
        database.delete("sqlite_sequence", null, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}

public String updatedata2(ContentValues cv, int pass_id) {
    String result = "Successfully Updated Status of notify";

    String qry = "'" + pass_id + "'";

    database.update(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME_02, cv, "w_id" + "=" + qry,
            null);

    return result;
}

 ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put("is_like", "N");
                AlbumsPhotosImpl albmImpl = new AlbumsPhotosImpl(
                        FullPhotoAlbumActivity.this);
                albmImpl.updatedata2(cv,
                        Integer.parseInt(photo_id_array.get(

                        position).toString()));
```

5) WebService Response

```
   protected class GetJury extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        // pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        // pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        // pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String android_id = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
                Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        String w = "";

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();


        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Constant.SERVER);


        try {

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                    2);

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("f", "functionname"));
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("xyz",
             xyz));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            w = EntityUtils.toString(response1.getEntity());

            // pDialog.dismiss();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.v("error", e + "");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return w;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String jsonText) {

        try {
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Log.i("TIME_S", time + "");
            JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(jsonText);

            String status = jobject.getString("status");

            if (status.equals("1")) {


               JSONArray event_json2 = new JSONArray();
                try {
                    event_json2 = jobject.getJSONArray("result");
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

                // JSONObject jsonObject = jobject.getJSONObject("result");

                //for (int j = 0; j < event_json2.length(); j++) {

                //  JSONObject jsonObject = event_json2.getJSONObject(j);

                //}



                JSONObject event_json_res = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    event_json_res = jobject.getJSONObject("results");
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

                JSONObject event_json_votedata = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    event_json_votedata = event_json_res.getJSONObject("votedata");
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }   


                UpdateImpl updateimpl = new UpdateImpl(SplaceActivity.this);
                updateimpl.deleteAll();


                Log.i("TIME_DB_RESET_DONE", time + "");
                // updates
                ArrayList<UpdateData> updateDataToBeInserted = new ArrayList<UpdateData>();
                Iterator<String> keys = event_json_updates.keys();
                while (keys.hasNext()) {

                    String i = keys.next();
                    JSONObject jsona = event_json_updates.getJSONObject(i);

                    String timestamp = jsona.getString("timestamp");


                    updateDataToBeInserted.add(new UpdateData(0, "0",Long.parseLong(timestamp)));

                }
                updateimpl.insertAll(updateDataToBeInserted);


            } else if (status.equals("0")) {

                // Util.show_error_dialog(LoginActivity.this,
                // "Username and Password does not match");

                // Util.show_error_dialog(context,
                // "Oops, something went wrong. Please try again after sometime.");
            }

            // pDialog.dismiss();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.v("error", e + "");
            // pDialog.dismiss();
            Log.e("GetBearerTokenTask", "Error:" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this lines. **give the 0 in quotes**

you declate `KEY_BALANCE` as text but you are entering integer value in this field. That's y you are getting error

```
 public long insert_table(String BANKNAME,String TYPE,
            String ACCNUM, String BALANCE,
            String EXPIRYDATE) {

    this.insertStmt.bindString(1, BANKNAME);
    this.insertStmt.bindString(2, TYPE);
    this.insertStmt.bindString(3, ACCNUM);
    this.insertStmt.bindString(4, BALANCE);
    this.insertStmt.bindString(5, EXPIRYDATE);

    return this.insertStmt.executeInsert();

    }
```

Call this method where you are trying to insert values as

```
DataHelper dh = new DataHelper(this);
dh.insert_table("Bank Account","","","0","");
```

Comment: Error! The database has not been created when running it.

Comment: No, its not because of the integer that im getting error. when i input from a form, it saves it in the database even if i have declare text and enter an integer, i just want when i run my application for the first time, 3 row automatically inserted in the database.

Comment: now only you told no, 3 row automatically inserted in the database. then wats the problem again

Answer (score 1):

Try to understand this code will help you to understand in better way:

```
package com.example.lalit.myapplication;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.text.method.HideReturnsTransformationMethod;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Currency;

/**
 * Created by lalit on 7/30/2015.
 */
public class HotOrNot {

  public final static String KEY_ROWID="_id";
    public final static String KEY_NAME="persion_name";
    public final static String KEY_HOTNESS="persion_hotness";
    public final static String KEY_SUB="OS";

    public final static String DATABASE_NAME="HotOrNotdb";
    public final static String DATABASE_TABLE="peopleTable";
    public final static int DATABASE_VERSION=1;

    public static Dbhelper ourHelper;
    public final Context ourContext;
    public SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table peopleTable(_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "persion_name text not null, persion_hotness text not null);";


    public class Dbhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
         public Dbhelper(Context context)
         {
             super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
         }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);


         /*   db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + DATABASE_NAME +"("+
             KEY_ROWID +"INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+
             KEY_NAME  +"TEXT NOT NULL,"+
             KEY_HOTNESS+"TEXT NOT NULL);"*/


             //);




        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
             db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST "+DATABASE_TABLE);
              onCreate(db);

        }


    }
    public HotOrNot(Context c)
    {
        ourContext=c;
    }

    public HotOrNot open() throws SQLException
    {
        ourHelper=new Dbhelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase=ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
   public void close()
   {
        ourHelper.close();
   }
 public long createEntry(String name,String hotness)
 {
     ourDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO peopleTable (persion_name,persion_hotness) VALUES('Lalit','Kushwah')");
     ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
      cv.put(KEY_NAME,name);
      cv.put(KEY_HOTNESS,hotness);

      return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null,cv);

 }
    public String getData()
    {
        String[] col=new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_NAME,KEY_HOTNESS};
        Cursor c=ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE,col,null,null,null,null,null);
        String result="";
        int irow=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iname=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
        int ihot=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_HOTNESS);

        for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext())
        {
           result=result+c.getString(irow)+"  "+c.getString(iname)+"  "+c.getString(ihot)+ "\n";

        }



        return result;
    }
}
```