# Android, SQLite

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

I have question to you.

How can I insert below' ID into database table ?

```
 @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    id = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(((SpinnerObject)spSpinner.getSelectedItem()).getDatabaseId()));
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have selected department with ID: " + id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onItemSelected database id: " + id);
                }
```

I want to insert this ID to the second table in my database. How can I do it ?

Comment: see [here](http://pastebin.com/U1gStfKs)

Answer (score 0):

First you create a database and a table where you store IDs.

After that, just simply use a query to add ID to that table :

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (column1, column2, column3,...columnN)]  
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...valueN);
```

View more here: [Insert in SQLite Database android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191816/insert-in-sqlite-database-android)