# Images in the drawable folder is Not Showing in android

Tags: android, android-drawable

I was creating a BottomSheetDialogFragment, in bottom sheet dialog frament i placed a gridview inside the Scroll view and i want to display Some Images in my gridview, for that first i planned to save images(manually) in firebase and i planned to show those images in Gridview but unfortunately i dont know how to do and i refer some tutorials which also not helps me

So i planned to save images in drawable folder and i wish to dispaly in the Gridview, after i saved the images in drawable folder and i can get those images names in my code like `R.drawable.music-box.png`

this music-box was not showing when i type `R.drawable.` what is the problem pls help me also if posible pls say

how to save images manually in firebase and  display in gridvirew in bottomsheetdialogframents

thanks .

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rename all ur filenames without highfen( i mean (-)) ex : music-box into musicbox

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191816/insert-in-sqlite-database-android

Answer (score 1):

rename your image dash not valid character try music_box and try to add image by using resource manager